# Is there a way to change the number of significant digits shown (for the follow path constraint)?

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm using the follow path constraint on a very long path. 
[image]

I would like to see the offset with more decimal places when I'm changing frames. Is there a way to increase the number of digits shown?

If not, is there another way to see the offset value with more than 3 significant places?

Comment: if i understood ur question is that u want to increase the number 0.005 to say 0.000005 if so then in the properties panel go to scene tab and under units change from none to metric and u can change what number u need from 0.005 to 0.000005